# Algebraic curve contained in plane or only intersects it finitely many times

Tags: algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $C\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is an irreducible real-algebraic curve that meets a plane infinitely many times. Is it true that $C$ must be contained in this plane?

I'm working on a paper that's loosely related to algebraic geometry, but I am probably lacking even basic knowledge about algebraic curves.

Comment: Did you check it for the plane $z=0$? If yes, then rotate your plane and the curve.

Comment: @markvs I'm sorry, I need a little more to go on. How do I check it for $z=0$?

Comment: You have to come up with a curve.depenending.on$z$ which has infinitely many points with.$z=0$ or prove that it does not exist.

Comment: The point @markvs is making is that if such a curve exists, then it can be transformed to a similar curve where the plane in question is $z=0$.  Once you've demonstrated that, you've reduced the question to the (presumably) easier problem of determining whether this is possible for the plane $z=0$.

Comment: @markvs I don't think that curve is irreducible (it's the disjoint union of a parabola and a circle per my plot). OP, my suggestion is to note that the intersection of $C$ with said plane is a closed subset of $C$. What do you know about the topology of irreducible curves?

Comment: @markvs The second equation yields the union of planes $z = 0$ and $x + y - 5 = 0$. The intersection of the latter plane with the paraboloid formed by $x^2 + y^2 - 1 - z = 0$ is a parabola, which can be seen by substituting $y = 5 - x$.
Edit: Just saw the new thing you added, why is $z = x^2 +  (5 - x)^2 - 1$ not a parabola?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: Points in 3D have three coordinates, so $z=x^2+(5-x)^2-1$ is not a curve. I do not claim that the curve is irreducible, it is reducible with two components one of which is a circle and another looks like parabola.

Comment: @markvs  Edit, ah I see my mistake, I should've said that equation as well as $y = x - 5$. But OP's question was about irreducible curves, so this is not a counterexample.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: OK. The curve is reducible. Unfortunately it does not help the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response is based on a comment from paul blart math cop. One definition of dimension is the maximal length $d$ of a chain $V_0\subsetneq...\subsetneq V_d=V$ of irreducible closed subsets. Since an algebraic curve has degree $1$ and points are closed, there are no irreducible algebraic varieties of intermediate size.

Assume the intersection of $C$ with the plane $P$ contains infinitely many points. Because every algebraic set may be written as the union of finitely many irreducible algebraic sets, $C\cap P$ must contain an irreducible algebraic variety with more than one point. But because $C$ had dimension $1$, this must be the whole curve, proving the claim.